# Birt 4.5 set Page Variable

Tags: eclipse, birt

i want to do a report with birt.
i need to do a list of people.

i have already done the view of this list but i need to put the first name and the name of the last people on the page and put it at the header of the master page.

so at the data set i have n° ETU, Nom, Prénom
and i have make 3 Page Variable : StartName, EndName and RangeName

the RangeName will look like :  "StartName - EndName"

On Onprepare script for the layout i have initialise the Variable like :

```
StartName=null;
EndName=null;
RangeName=null;
```

at this state the report are correctly generated

then i try to put on the Data(Nom) onPageBreak :

```
if (StartName==null)
{
Report.context.setPageVariable("StartName",value);
}
Report.context.setPageVariable("EndName",value);
```

and at the Master Page i put an AutoText Variable (RangeName)
and i didn't put the code to concat the StartName and the EndName in RangeName
because i get an error :

```
org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.EngineException: Error happened while running the report.
.....
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.content.impl.DataContent cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
.....
```

could you help me to resolve this error ?